# replacing and hiding gridcontainers

Tags: javascript, html

**This is what I have:**

I have a gridcontainer with three cells where one cell contains three buttons. Each button displays an image below the container.

My javascript code is supposed to make the image disappear if a button is pressed twice butdoes not do so atm. The only way to make it disappear is to either press another picture hence replacing it with a new pic or reload the page.

**This is what I want to do:**

Instead of replacing and hiding images, I want to replace and hide gridcontainers. So instead of buttons showing pictures they will show a couple of cells with a mix of text and images. The content and layout on this will change when a new button is change, and will totally disappear when the same button is pressed twice. Is this doable.

**This is my current javascript:**

```
function changeImage(element){
if(document.getElementById('imageReplace').src==element){
     document.getElementById('imageReplace').src="";
    } else{ document.getElementById('imageReplace').src=element; }
```

**it is activated by this html:**

```
<div class="cell"><h2>Top reasons you should have a digital self     
defense</h2>
 
<button class="infobutt"   
onclick="changeImage('survcap1.jpeg');">Intellectual  
freedom</button> 
<button class="infobutt"  
onclick="changeImage('survcap2.jpeg');">protect vulnerable 
groups</button>
<button class="infobutt" 
onclick="changeImage('survcap3.jpeg');">Take control over your 
life</button></div>"
```

**and correponds further with this html (Situated outside and below the container, also below main tag):**

```
<img src="" alt="Images" id="imageReplace"/>
```

**What is wrong with my current code and how can I improve it to suit my purpose?**

Comment: First off, your if-statement in your JS seems to be missing a closing parenthesis. Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @user1599011 ah that was just a typo in my question here on stackflow, fixed it now. No error in the console :/

Comment: What do you see if, at the top of your function, you write the src and element to the console?